# SSRS 2008 (not R2) Export to PDF Works Different from 2 different servers

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have a QA and a production server that have SSRS 2008 installed on them (not R2).

On the production server, I have a report A.

From my workstation, I open a browser and run the report on the production server, and I export it to PDF format.

I deploy this same report to the QA server, accessing the same database.

From my workstation, I open a browser and run the report on the QA server, and I export it to PDF format.

The PDF from the QA server has page breaks at different places.

I tried deleting the reports from the QA Server and re-deploying them, restarting the server, and I even downloaded the RDL file from the Production Server through the browser, and deploying that, but the page breaks still are different.

I looked at the installed fonts, I made sure that the database

The only difference I can see, is that the QA Server has Microsoft SQL Server SP3 and the production server has Microsoft SQL Server SP1 installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With any QA task I would try to match the Prod environment as far as possible. If you are running SP3 on QA and SP1 on Prod you are not using the same software, so I would expect some differences in the output to occur.

I would either downgrade QA to SP1 or (preferably) upgrade Prod to SP3.  This will probably have other benefits from the other bug fixes in SP3.

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for responding. The environments started off the same - in fact they are all VMs built off the same image, but then an IT manager decided to apply the service packs to the dev and QA servers without warning. I'll give downgrading a shot on the QA first since the reports dont seem to work in SP3.